# How to migrate parts from one active database to another active database?

Tags: mysql, database, content-management-system

I'm creating a content management system with a centralized database for all the users on the platform, a user could have one or more websites.

When a user's website is finished for filling content we put the website on a test domain with a centralized test database.

After filling the content the user gives us a call and we migrate the website to a new host and migrate/merge the data from our centralized test database to our centralized production database.

What's the best solution for doing this? Because I'm afraid this is going to cause a lot of problems in the future (data that isn't in sync, data that gets overwritten or worse the CMS breaks...).

**To sum it all up:** How to migrate parts from one active database to another active database

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Use **MySQLDump** as:

```
mysqldump -hREMOTE_HOST -uroot -pREMOTEpwd --opt --compress REMOTEdb | mysql -uroot -pLOCALpwd LOCALdb
```

This command can be executed on the destination server and it will pull the contents of the source database, recreating all tables and data.

> Using this approach would require taking the source
>   database server down to avoid loss of data.

**2.** As per subsequent requirement, you need **incremental backup plan**.

> An incremental backup only backs up data that changed since the
>   previous backup. This technique provides additional flexibility in
>   designing a backup strategy and reduces required storage for backups.

Incremental backup is enabled through an option to the **mysqlbackup** command.

Sample command line arguments to start `mysqlbackup` are:

```
# Information about data files can be retrieved through the database connection.
# Specify connection options on the command line.
mysqlbackup --user=dba --password --port=3306 \
  --with-timestamp --backup-dir=/export/backups \
  backup

# Or we can include the above options in the configuration file
# under [mysqlbackup], and just specify the configuration file
# and the 'backup' operation.
mysqlbackup --defaults-file=/usr/local/mysql/my.cnf backup

# Or we can specify the configuration file as above, but
# override some of those options on the command line.
mysqlbackup --defaults-file=/usr/local/mysql/my.cnf \
  --compress --user=backupadmin --password --port=18080 \
  backup
```

The `--user` and the `--password` we specify are used to connect to the MySQL server.

The `--with-timestamp` option places the backup in a subdirectory created under the directory we have specified above. The name of the backup subdirectory is formed from the date and the clock time of the backup run.

See the full reference [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.7/en/mysqlbackup.incremental.html) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.10/en/mysqlbackup.html).

Comment: This would be nice if I want to merge the whole database but I only want to merge a part of it. For example website #13 is filling it's contents on the test-database and website #2 is already running on the production-database for a couple of month's. How to merge #13's data on the production-database without losing #2's data.

Comment: You should do that replication instead. Also change your question as well

Comment: I will provide replication solution shortly

Comment: What do you mean by replication? And on what parts I need to change my question?